# Why is my multi-column query dramatically slower than the corresponding single-column queries, even with a multi-column index?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
from stop_times 
WHERE (departure_time BETWEEN '02:41' AND '05:41' 
       OR departure_time BETWEEN '26:41' AND '29:41') 
    AND stop_times.stop_id IN(51511,51509,51508,51510,6,53851,51522,51533)
```

that returns 134 rows in ~800ms. If I split it:

```
SELECT * 
from stop_times 
WHERE (departure_time BETWEEN '02:41' AND '05:41' 
       OR departure_time BETWEEN '26:41' AND '29:41')
```

returns ~110k rows in ~10ms and

```
SELECT * 
from stop_times 
WHERE stop_times.stop_id IN(51511,51509,51508,51510,6,53851,51522,51533)
```

returns ~5k rows in ~100ms.

I tried using both a multi-column index (departure_time and stop_id) as well as 2 separate indexes, but in either case the first query can't seem to take less than ~800ms. My stop_times table has about 3.5M rows. Is there anything I could be missing and that would significantly speed up that first query?

**UPDATE 1: SHOW TABLE CREATE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `stop_times` (
  `trip_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `departure_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `stop_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index_stop_times_on_trip_id` (`trip_id`),
  KEY `index_stop_times_on_departure_time_and_stop_id` (`departure_time`,`stop_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

stop_id and trip_id being varchars instead of integers is beyond my control unfortunately...

**UPDATE 2:** `EXPLAIN` for `departure_time, stop_id` multi-column index:

```
select_type: SIMPLE
type: range
rows: 239084
```

`EXPLAIN` for `stop_id, departure_time` multi-column index:

```
select_type: SIMPLE
type: range
rows: 141
```

**UPDATE 3:** `EXPLAIN` for `IN(51511,51509,51508,51510,6,53851,51522,51533)`

```
select_type: SIMPLE
type: ALL
rows: 3556973 (lol)
```

`EXPLAIN` for `IN("51511","51509","51508","51510","6","53851","51522","51533")`

```
select_type: SIMPLE
type: range
rows: 141
```

Comment: Can we see an output of SHOW TABLE CREATE tablename?  Or at least the indexes.  Index order can matter on WHERE clauses.  Also, curious to make sure the datatypes are what I would expect them to be.  Edit:  You might also want to do an EXPLAIN statement and see what index options MySQL is seeing.  I don't quite remember how MySQL handles date ranges and indexes.

Comment: @melihcelik No, that is not correct. The order of the index is very important, but has nothing whatsoever to do with the order in the query. There isn't really room in this comment box to explain it properly though.

Comment: @Corbin see updated question. Did an EXPLAIN statement and MySQL is showing index_stop_times_on_departure_time_and_stop_id...

Comment: Agreed with @Ariel, the two main things with multi-column indexes is to ensure you use the fields listed in the index from left to right without skipping any, and that the index column order allows the system to throw away the most data possible as early as possible. The order of the fields within the query is not important.

Comment: I will delete my previous comment as Ariel and Dave are right. I sometimes confuse where clause ordering on partitioned tables with multi-column indexes on regular queries, whatever. [Multi-column indexes manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) explains this perfect.

Comment: On a side note, this table would surely benefit from partitioning (if you can use it). I am not really aware of the capabilities of MySQL in this field, but I suppose it supports RANGE partitions.

Comment: If you get queries returning in 10ms, no need for thinking about partitioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you create an index `stop_id, departure_time`? Because `departure_time, stop_id` will do absolutely nothing.

This is a *really* hard one - it has every possible bad thing for dealing with indexes :(

You have a range, an OR and a non contiguous IN - it doesn't get worse than that.

Try `stop_id, departure_time` and if it doesn't help then there is nothing much you can do short of switching to PostgreSQL.

---

You can also try rewriting the query as:

```
SELECT * 
from stop_times 
WHERE ( stop_times.stop_id IN(51511,51509,51508,51510,6,53851,51522,51533)
      AND departure_time BETWEEN '02:41' AND '05:41'
      )
   OR ( stop_times.stop_id IN(51511,51509,51508,51510,6,53851,51522,51533)
      AND departure_time BETWEEN '26:41' AND '29:41' 
      )
```

or:

```
    SELECT * 
    from stop_times 
    WHERE ( stop_times.stop_id IN(51511,51509,51508,51510,6,53851,51522,51533)
          AND departure_time BETWEEN '02:41' AND '05:41'
          )
UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    from stop_times 
    WHERE ( stop_times.stop_id IN(51511,51509,51508,51510,6,53851,51522,51533)
          AND departure_time BETWEEN '26:41' AND '29:41' 
          )
```

Comment: Huh, making the index `stop_id, departure_time` makes the query even slower. It's now taking 3.54s.

Comment: @samvermette Are you sure you are not checking cached time? Because MySQL will cache queries by default and if you run the same one twice you won't get useful timing info. Change the query in any way (even a space) so it won't be found in the cache.

Comment: @samvermette also, please post the `explain` output for each type of index you make (i.e. I would like to see 3 different versions of the explain - one for each index possibility).

Comment: @samvermette And please run `analyze table stop_times;` after each time you create an index (it may not be necessary, but just in case).

Comment: Adding quotes to my variables in my `IN` statement brings it down to 4.7ms. The quotes make sense, since `stop_id` is a varchar, but why would it speed up the query that much?

Comment: @samvermette Man I actually thought of that, but in a quick test on my machine it made no difference. It could be that without a quote it is trying to convert the column to an integer first, and then compare it (rather than the reverse). (i.e. '001' and '1' both equal 1 - so it depends on if you do a string compare or an integer compare). But please!!! Check that you are not getting cached results for this very fast result.

Comment: I confirm that this is not a cached result. I tried reverting to my old multi-column index (`departure_time, stop_id`) and I'm getting 800ms, with or without quotes. Combination of your answer + adding the quotes is making this super fast. Will add the EXPLAIN for the 2 in the original question. Thanks dude!

Comment: @samvermette Well now I'm going to want to see an explain for with and without quotes too :)

Comment: I agree, `(departure_time, stop_id)` index is pretty much useless. Keep the `(stop_id, departure_time)` index and a simple `departure_time` index (for your 2nd query).

Comment: If `stop_id` is a varchar, it's better to use quotes in the `IN(...)`.

Comment: Added quotes EXPLAIN to my original question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibility you could try, which is to prepare a list of all the times that occur within both ranges first, and then stick them together in a large `IN` clause - it may look horrible, but it will remove the `OR` condition which isn't helping your query... And you should be able to build the `IN` string using your favourite programming language :)

```
WHERE departure_time IN ('02:41','02:42','02:43', ... '26:41','26:42','26:43', ... etc )
```

Your query contains two blocks of three hours, which equates to 6 * 60 = 360 entries in the `IN` clause...

Worth a try at least...